# Como atualizar um elemento externo ao p:datatable com selectionMode="single"

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

Estou utilizando o componente `p:dataTable` do `primefaces`  com `selectionMode="single"` que utiliza `RadioButton` como seleção.

Gostaria que quando selecionasse uma linha da tabela atualizasse minha label com o valo do perfil selecionado, mas isso não ocorre.

```
<p:dataTable 
    id="gridControleAcesso" 
    var="perfil" reflow="true"
    rowIndexVar="index" 
    value="#{controleDeAcessoController.perfis}"
    selection="#{controleDeAcessoController.perfilSelecionado}"
    rowKey="#{perfil.id}"
    disabledSelection="#{controleDeAcessoController.usuario == null}"
    update="comboPrestadoresDeServicos"
    imediate="true"
    >
     <p:ajax event="rowSelect" update="labelTest" process="@form" imediate="true" />
     <p:column selectionMode="single" headerText="Acesso"  >

    </p:column>
    <p:column headerText="Perfil" >
        <h:outputText value="#{perfil.nome}" />
    </p:column> 
</p:dataTable>

<h:outputText id="labelTest" value="a:: #{controleDeAcessoController.perfilSelecionado.nome}" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solucionei da seguinte forma,  adcionei a class `hide-radio-selection` e criei uma classe que remove o `radio-button` padrão e criei o meu próprio `radio-button`, conforme abaixo

```
<p:dataTable 
    id="gridControleAcesso" 
    var="perfil" reflow="true"
    rowIndexVar="index" 
    value="#{controleDeAcessoController.perfis}"
    selection="#{controleDeAcessoController.perfilSelecionado}"
    rowKey="#{perfil.id}"
    disabledSelection="#{controleDeAcessoController.usuario == null}"
    update="comboPrestadoresDeServicos"
    imediate="true"
    >
     <p:column selectionMode="single" headerText="Acesso" styleClass="hide-radio-selection text-center"  >
<p:selectOneRadio  value="#{controleDeAcessoController.perfilSelecionado}" unselectable="true" disabled="#{controleDeAcessoController.usuario == null}">
                                <p:ajax event="change" update="@form" listener="#{controleDeAcessoController.atualizarSelecao()}" process="@this" />
                                <f:selectItem itemLabel="" itemValue="#{perfil}" />
                            </p:selectOneRadio>
    </p:column>
    <p:column headerText="Perfil" >
        <h:outputText value="#{perfil.nome}" />
    </p:column> 
</p:dataTable>
```

Answer (score 0):

Olá!

Não sei é este o caso, mas baseado no código que tu colocou, acredito que possa ser a questão de como é formado o id dos elementos quando a página é renderizada.

Por exemplo:

Se a sua view estiver assim:

```
<h:form id="formulario">
     <h:outputText id="labelTest" value="a:: #controleDeAcessoController.perfilSelecionado.nome}" />
</h:form>
```

O id do teu label vai ser gerado no seguinte formato:

```
id="formulario:labelTest"
```

Tu tem duas opções pra atualizar o componente:
1) Declara o formulário usando prependId="false"

```
<h:form id="formulario" prependId="false"></h:form>
```

E daí tu pode deixar o teu update como está, ou

2) No update tu usa o caminho completo começando com ':'

```
<p:ajax event="rowSelect" update=":formulario:labelTest" process="@form" imediate="true" />
```

Outra opção é que, quando se utiliza o `RadioButton`, o evento que ele dispara é o `rowSelectRadio` e não o `rowSelect`.

Comment: Obrigado pela, resposta, mas infelizmente os seletores não solucionou o meu problema